# Question has 0 vote, but has given me positive reputation?

Tags: support, downvotes, bounty

Recently I asked a question on SO. As it usually happens with my questions ("doh!), it got voted down. Two days later I decided to offer some bounty for a good answer. Then the vote got set to 0 votes, and I seem to have gotten +9 reputation of the question.

So, what happened ? Did I regain the reputation lost from the earlier downvotes?

Comment: Expand the reputation history and you'll find the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 3 up votes (+15) and 3 down votes (-6) on your question. Net score is +9. Number of votes is +3 -3 = 0.

See https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868955/evdzhan-mustafa?tab=reputation

[image]

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation for more information.